# vue component should passing primitive type .. how about generator component ? (ex: form generator)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have already read lots of doc about vue component, Mention about passing primitive type value to component.

Of course I know why it should pass primitive value to component, but how about the generator component like form generator !? It must pass array or object to generate ..

```
<i-table
  :title="exampleTable.title"
  :class-name="exampleTable.className"
  :model="agents"
  :schema="exampleTable.schema"
  :buttons="exampleTable.buttons">
</i-table>
```

---

```
exampleTable: {
  title: '',
  className: 'table-striped',
  schema: [{
    name: 'email',
    displayName: 'user.email',
    tag: ''
  }, {
    name: 'name',
    displayName: 'user.name',
    tag: ''
  }, {
    name: 'createdAt',
    displayName: 'user.createdAt',
    tag: 'date'
  }, {
    name: '',
    tag: 'array',
    itemActions: [{
      name: 'button.edit',
      type: 'button',
      class: 'btn-outline-secondary btn-small',
      method: data => { this.showEditModal(data, 'edit') },
      disabled: false
    }, {
      name: 'sidebar.plan',
      type: 'button',
      class: 'btn-outline-secondary btn-small',
      method: data => { this.showPayModal(data, 'show') },
      disabled: false
    }]
  }],       
  buttons: [{
    text: 'button.add',
    class: 'btn-primary pull-right',
    method: data => { this.showPayModal(data, 'add') },
    disabled: false
  }]
```

here is my example, how to make without passing primitive type value ..?

Is there any idea to make better vue2 ?

Comment: Please post some code to explain what you are asking about / elaborate more to explain what you exactly want to achieve (with code examples)

Comment: You do not need to pass a primitive type as a property. It can be any javascript object, function, type, whatever.

Comment: I know..but it seem not a good idea to pass array or object to component..or I just miaunderstand something?

Comment: https://github.com/pablohpsilva/vuejs-component-style-guide#keep-component-props-primitive